# Facebook SDK 4: shared videos change URL over time

Tags: facebook, sdk, video-streaming

I'm using FB SDK to share videos.
I already have permission for user_video, already approved.
I collect "source" field graph from an android app:

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "picture,source,id,title");
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me/videos/uploaded", params, HttpMethod.GET,
```

I noticed that after a couple of days the video is no more available and if I make a new grph request, it returns a new source url.
Is there a way of retrieving a fixed url or I need to perform new requests on a daily base?
Thank you

Comment: Facebook CDN URLs are to be considered “transient”, and should not be stored for long-term use.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This is also for Images? Is there an other way, for example to use "embedded" fields?

Comment: Yes. For everything that’s on their CDNs.